# MYSQL delete statement deletes too many rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, firebase-authentication, sql-delete

I have a table for users in my MYSQL db like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `myDatabase`.`user` ( 
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`login` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL ,
`uid` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL , 
`email` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL , 
`user_type` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

uid is provided by firebase when a user logs in (strings such as 3LmgcBeCUNW1lfMKCQcoI8Xkxai1
 or DrFblVatVdacokhcQCuwb8DK13q1.

My project has a delete user option that calls the query:

```
public function deleteProfile($uid) {
            $memberDelete = $this->_db->prepare("DELETE FROM user WHERE uid = :uid");
            $memberDelete->bindParam(':uid',$uid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $resp = $memberDelete->execute();
            if(!$resp) {
                throw new PDOException('member couldn't be removed');
            }
            $memberDelete->closeCursor();
            return "member successfully removed";
        }
```

When I do this, it deletes way too many users.  I tried deleting based on email instead of UID and it deleted all of the users.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to permanently erase data in this way?

Comment: This is weird. Its hard to believe that your query deletes more than one user. Also shouldn't the uid column be unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
$memberDelete->bindParam(':uid', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

You are binding your param as an integer, while obviously it's a string. This generates a chain of implicit conversions that ends up deleting more rows that you intend.

Instead, you want:

```
$memberDelete->bindParam(':uid', $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```